# How do I refresh the environment variables in python after impersonating a user?

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables, advapi32

I have been working on allowing someone to impersonate a user, ( see: [Access Violation in LogonUserW in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51251086/access-violation-in-logonuserw-in-python-3/51252971#51252971) )

I have verified this as os.getlogin() returns a different user now, and file-access permissions behavior changed accordingly to the impersonated user.

However I noticed that the environment variables does not change, since they are cached upon startup. What could I do, so that I might be able to refresh the environment variables for the impersonated user.